# What is the best way to show a message on Apple Watch independently of the active interface controller?

Tags: ios, watchkit

I would like to display a local message (generated by WatchKit code) on the Apple Watch. My problem is that the message may be triggered by a code segment outside of the currently active interface controller.

What is the best way to modally present a new interface controller independent of the currently active (top-most) interface controller?

One way would be to get a pointer to the currently active interface controller. But how to do this in an easy way?

- One possible solution is to use a global property that holds a pointer to the currently active interface controller. It gets updated in the `willActivate` methods of all interface controllers.
- Another solution would be to always pass the pointer to the currently active interface controller to all methods that may want to show a message.
- Is there an easier way to get a pointer to the top-most interface controller?

Well, I'm not even convinced that the above approach is a good one. What if the top-most controller is dismissed shortly after presenting the interface controller with the message? Then the message is probably not shown very long or not at all.

Is it possible to modally present the message interface controller on top of everything independent of the currently active (top-most) interface controller?

Should I use local notifications? Is there something like UIAlertView?

What is the best and easiest way to solve this problem?

Comment: You can have one universal alert `WKInterfaceController` that you can present anywhere and pass in a string to display.

Comment: Thank you. How can I present it? Do you have a link to a page with an example or so?

Comment: Just use a regular `- presentControllerWithName:context:` and pass in a string as a context so that your alertview can take the string and display it.

Comment: Ok, how do I call `presentControllerWithName:context:` if I'm not "in" another interface controller, i.e., from a method in a subclass of NSObject, for example?

Comment: You can pass the NSObject an instance of self for it to presentController in. Apple's shifting to presenting alerts on the main VC, such as the iOS UIAlertController, so you would use the same workarounds for the watch as you would for iOS.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are a genius! I did not know that it is possible to present another interface controller from the main interface controller when the latter is not even active. But it works - I just tried it. Excellent! My current solution is now to store a pointer to the main interface controller in a global variable (using `extern`) and then presenting from this main interface controller. Why don't you add a short answer below. I'll be happy to accept it and vote it up.

Comment: It sounds like you have your answer, but I'll at least offer another perspective. You can keep track of your interface controllers by reference if you pass them in their context. I recently wrote-up a description of the technique here: http://blog.mikeswanson.com/post/118761670244/advanced-watchkit-interface-controller-techniques

Comment: Thank you, Mike, I really have to read your blog posts now! It has been on my todo list for quite some time. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show a message independently of the active interface controller, it is possible to present an interface controller using `presentControllerWithName:context:` from the *main* interface controller (the one with the arrow in the storyboard). This works even if the *main* interface controller is not currently active.

For this solution to work, it is necessary that the method that calls `presentControllerWithName:context:` has a pointer to the *main* interface controller. This can be achieved by passing `self` from the *main* interface controller to other interface controllers and methods.

However, I sometimes want to show a message from an object deep down in the hierarchy. And I do not want to pass the pointer to the `main` interface controller to every method that possibly wants to display a message to the user.

So, my current solution is to store a pointer to the *main* interface controller in a global variable (using `extern`) and then presenting from this *main* interface controller.

Acknowledgements: I would like to thank "Schemetrical" and "Mike Swanson" for the comments that solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any UIAlertView or WKAlertView in WatchKit. You must initialize a new view controller with a text view, and pass it the string you want to show.

You can use this method to do so:

Swift:

```
presentControllerWithName([Name] , context: [String])
```

Objective-C:

```
- presentControllerWithName:context:
```